# Chrome message "Error - Virus detected" while downloading the source code of VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to download the source code of VSCode but Chrome says "Error - Virus detected" while I download it. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you share the link from where you are trying to download it.

Comment: And also a screenshot of the message.